# Play back audio streamed over http

Tags: java, audio, stream

I am working on a small instant messenger project that implements a custom encryption algorithm I've developed. However, networking isn't my strong area.

Basically, here I'm trying to provide a synchronized audio output stream using a one to many arches.

So, so far, I've managed to pipe out the audio over an HTTP connection in base64 encoded format, but here, I am stuck.

I have no idea how to play back the audio in real time, without reading the same audio data twice(overlap)

audio server

here's my server-side code, please be kind if I have mucked up the whole thing, but I think I've got this part working correctly.

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.139.
 */
package SIM.net.client.networking;

import DARTIS.crypt;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

public class audioServer {
    public static void start(String[] key) {
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
            TargetDataLine microphone = null;
            try {
                microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            try {
                microphone = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                microphone.open(format);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
            byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];
            microphone.start();             
            int bytesRead = 0;    
            do {

                    if (bytesRead >= 4096) {
                        byte[] audioData = out.toByteArray();
                    String base64img = Base64.encode(audioData);
                    String audioclip;
                    if (key.length > 9999) {
                    audioclip = crypt.inject(base64img, key);
                    } else {
                        audioclip = base64img;
                    }
                    audioHandler.setdata(audioclip);
                    bytesRead = 0;
                    out.reset();

                } else {
                    int numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                    System.out.println(bytesRead += numBytesRead);
                    out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                }

                }
                    while (true);
    }
}
```

audio handler

```
package SIM.net.client.networking;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class audioHandler
implements HttpHandler {
    public static String audiodata;

    public static void setdata(String imgdta) {
        audiodata = imgdta;
    }

    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        HashMap parameters = new HashMap();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(9991), 0);
        server.createContext("/audio", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
        audioServer.start(new String[3]);
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
            URI requestedUri = he.getRequestURI();
            String query = requestedUri.getRawQuery();
            he.sendResponseHeaders(200, audiodata.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").length());
            OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
            os.write(audiodata.toString().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please understand, this code was originally written to stream webcam snapshots over http in real time, one frame at a time, if this design isn't suitable for audio streaming, please point me in the right direction, I usually learn best from running examples, editing, and observing the changes in it's output, so any sample/example code would help greatly.(im not asking you to solve it for me 100%, just some pointers in the right direction and example code)

Comment: I should note here, that I do want to accomplish this with an internal http server in my jar, rather than streaming directly via sockets, so that the data is only transferred over the network on demand and can easily be relayed across the WWW, and accessible through simple http calls.

Comment: https://github.com/pdglobal/SIMJAVA/tree/master/SIMJAVA/src/main/java/SIM/net/client/networking

Comment: I've got it buffering 4kb of audio data at a time now properly. Now to just figure out how to take that buffered data, and turn it into a audible stream of sound data and output to the speakers...